# jQuery: inside one function, become aware of completed promise inside another function

Tags: jquery, deferred

## Some Context

Despite six hours of reading, including the official documentation, I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around the implementation of promises. (I get the core concept.) Inside a function X, I have Y number of ajax calls. I've been able to determine when all Y ajax calls have been completed (though, I still don't fully grasp *how* the syntax produces the result).

## The Need

However, I still need to make the *caller* of function X (another function) aware that all Y ajax calls have been completed. Here's a simplified / semi-pseudocode example. (I'm wondering if my previous attempts failed because of a scope issue, but I'm not seeing deferred object passed to functions in the examples I've seen. I decided to keep the example below "clean" instead of showing a particular failed attempt.)

```
$.fn.SendEmails = function (emailsToSend) {

    var emailSendingPromises = [];

    $.each(emailsToSend, function (i, p) {
        emailSendingPromises.push($.ajax({
            // relevant stuff
        })
        .done( function () {
            console.log('one email done');
        })
        .fail( function () {
            console.log('one email failed');
        }));
    });

    // when all promises have completed 
    $.when.apply($, emailSendingPromises).always(function () {
        console.log('all emails completed');
        // --- MAKE CALLER AWARE ALL EMAILS ARE COMPLETED ---
    });
}


$.fn.AnotherFunction = function () {

    $().SendEmails(emailsToSend);

    // --- BECOME AWARE THAT ALL EMAILS ARE COMPLETED ---

    // do other stuff only when all emails are completed AND some other things happen
}
```

Thank you very much for assistance! :)

Comment: Use a callback: `$.fn.SendEmails = function (emailsToSend, callback) { ... $.when.apply($, emailSendingPromises).always(function() { /*...*/ callback(); }); $().SendEmails(emailsToSend, functionWhichShouldBeCalledWhenMailsHaveBeenSend);`

Comment: @Andreas - Thank you for this. However, I need to do some other stuff inside AnotherFunction. E.g., when multiple promises are fulfilled (save data asynchronously, record errors asynchronously, send emails asynchronously), then display a message to the user. Unless I'm just missing something, at some point, I'm going to have to wait for all of those promise resolutions in one place, which is (part of) the purpose of AnotherFunction. I've updated the example to hopefully make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try `return`ing your `$.when` in your `SendEmails` function. Then, in your `AnotherFunction`, after you make this call: `$().SendEmails(emailsToSend)`, add a `.then()`:

```
$().SendEmails(emailsToSend).then(function() { /* other stuff */});
```

The `.then()` will fire only after the returned promise has resolved.

Comment: Oh, geez - I could have **sworn** I did that about 5 times so far today. Simple typo, maybe. Thanks very much for your help, and sorry for being silly.

Comment: no worries, happens to the best of us! glad i could help :)